# Maximise Browser window, RobotFramework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am learning RobotFramework, I have a simple script :

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  Simple Amazon.in demo
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${MESSAGE}  Hello, World

*** Test Cases ***
User must sign in to check out
    [Documentation]  This is some basic info about the test
    [Tags]  Smoke
    Open Browser  http://www.amazon.in  firefox
    Input text  id=twotabsearchtextbox  Ferrari 458
    Click Button  xpath=//div[@class='nav-search-submit nav-sprite']/input[@class='nav-input' and 1]
    Wait until page Contains  results for "Ferrari 458"
    Click Link  css=#result_0 a.s-access-detail-page
    Wait until Page Contains  Back to search results for "Ferrari 458"
    Click Button  id=add-to-cart-button
    Wait Until Page Contains  1 item added to Cart
```

Everything is working fine, but browser window is not maximized, plz help me, how can I do that.

This is my pip configuration

```
robotframework                 3.1
robotframework-requests        0.5.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary 3.2.0
selenium                       3.141.0
```

Answer (score 5):

To start with you can use the `Maximize Browser Window` Keyword after Open Browser.

If that does not work; there is possible fix that is suggested here: 
https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/issues/123

See if it resolves your issue. Let me know if it did.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
Open Browser    about:blank    safari
Maximize Browser Window
```

Hope help you.

Answer (score 1):

Open Browser  http://www.amazon.in  chrome

Maximize Browser Window

More info:
http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Maximize%20Browser%20Window

Answer (score 0):

If you need to maximize the browser window *before* opening the URL then you may want to add the step `Go To`:

```
    Open Browser            about:blank    Chrome
    Maximize Browser Window
    Go To                   https://google.com
```

Answer (score -1):

Common Test Setup

```
    [Documentation]  All test cases should use this in Test Setup.
    set test variable  ${BooleanLoggedIn}  ${False}
    Login Detail for Admin or Resp Decision
    run keyword if      "${REMOTE}"=="False"   run keywords  TFNR_Utilities.Open Chrome Maximized
    ...                 ELSE IF     "${REMOTE}"=="True"    run keywords  TFNR_Utilities.Run Tests on Cross Browser Platform
    ...                 ELSE        log   Check the value of Global variable 'REMOTE'
    SeleniumLibrary.Go To  ${LOGIN URL}
    SeleniumLibrary.Maximize Browser Window
    Login.Login To TFNR SPA UI  ${VALID USER}   ${VALID PASSWORD}
    #DB Data pull if required to Validate Dashboard Page dispaly Name and Default ACTING AS Resp Org Selection
    Set Tags  Browser_${BROWSER}    Tests_ON_${Environment}_Environment
    set test variable  ${BooleanLoggedIn}  ${True}
```